# How to make default dates null of px-rangepicker?

Tags: javascript, element, polymer-2.x, px-rangepicker

I'm using [**px-rangepicker**](https://www.predix-ui.com/#/components/px-rangepicker/) and I want to set it default check-in and check-out dates blank but could not find a way to do that. Both check-in and check-out dates are getting the current date. I lost a day to find out the way to make it blank.

My custom element looks like this:

```
<date-fields
            id="field"
            from-moment="{{fromMoment}}"
            to-moment="{{toMoment}}"
            time-zone="{{timeZone}}"
            date-format="{{dateFormat}}"
            time-format="{{timeFormat}}"
            hide-time="{{hideTime}}"
            block-future-dates="{{blockFutureDates}}"
            block-past-dates="{{blockPastDates}}"
            is-valid="{{isValid}}"
            show-time-zone="[[showTimeZone]]"
            prevent-notification-on-change
            resources="[[resources]]"
            language="[[language]]"
            formats="[[formats]]">
</date-fields>
```

Could you please give me a suggestion to make it easy?